# Error identifying the class due to the path (double slash)

Tags: flutter, dart

When compiling the Flutter application it raises this error. I can't find the solution because the classes are not mounted on paths with double slashes.

---

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
lib/app//models/account_model.dart:118:23: Error: A value of type 'AccountModel/*1*/' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AccountModel/*2*/'.

- 'AccountModel/*1*/' is from 'package:mychildren/app//models/account_model.dart' ('lib/app//models/account_model.dart').
- 'AccountModel/*2*/' is from 'package:mychildren/app/models/account_model.dart' ('lib/app/models/account_model.dart').
  globals.account = this;
  ^
  lib/app//models/account_model.dart:120:10: Error: A value of type 'OrgModel/*1*/' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'OrgModel/*2*/'.
- 'OrgModel/*1*/' is from 'package:mychildren/app//models/org_model.dart' ('lib/app//models/org_model.dart').
- 'OrgModel/*2*/' is from 'package:mychildren/app/models/org_model.dart' ('lib/app/models/org_model.dart').
  .firstWhere((igreja) => igreja.docid == this.ig);
  ^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/eduardo/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' line: 1350
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/eduardo/development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).

---

flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.8, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale
pt-BR)
• Flutter version 3.16.8 on channel stable at
/Users/eduardo/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 67457e669f (7 days ago), 2024-01-16 16:22:29 -0800
• Engine revision 6e2ea58a5c
• Dart version 3.2.5
• DevTools version 2.28.5

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/eduardo/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
• ANDROID_HOME = /Users/eduardo/Library/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 15A507
• CocoaPods version 1.14.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.2)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.80.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 12
(API 31) (emulator)
• macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.0
23A344 darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google
Chrome 120.0.6099.234

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

I hope to compile the program.

Comment: Somewhere in your project you have `import 'package:mychildren/app/models/account_model.dart';` and somewhere else you have `import 'package:mychildren/app//models/account_model.dart';` (and same for `org_model.dart`).  Fix your `import`s to be consistent.  I'd start by searching through your project directory for all occurrences of `//`.

Comment: Thanks #jamesdlin.I found a "//" reference in another class in the import.